# bash return value in pipe to bash

Tags: bash, pipe

We have a script, with a return code. For example

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 42
```

which is works fine:

```
$ ./script ; echo $?
42
```

but if i go:

```
$ bash << EOF
./script ; echo $?
EOF
0
```

so it prints 0, while one would expect it to still print 42

Comment: You don't have any pipes here, you're using bash to process a heredoc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$?` is being expanded before executing the script.  If you don't want your variables to expand in the `heredoc` (not a pipe) put single quotes around the name:

```
bash <<'EOF'
./script; echo $?
EOF
```

That wil prevent `$?` from being expanded while passing the string to the new `bash` command.  It will, instead, be evaluated in the string which is what you seem to be going for.